# How to cluster utc in milliseconds to months which belongs

Tags: go

Every document in `Mongo` has `timestamp in millisecond`s and I get array of documents as result of query.
How to cluster data to `array of arrays` where inner array are documents which `belongs to same month` ?
( Have to to do this also for `weeks`, week starts at `Monday` and the last day is `Sunday`).

Comment: I hardly understand your question but the title seems to ask something different than what the text is.

Comment: @inf For example if I have 1436795473 I should know that is July, Monday, today, for example

Answer (score 1):

You can get the month and weekday with the time package:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    ms := int64(0)
    t := time.Unix(0, ms*int64(time.Millisecond))
    fmt.Println(t.Month(), t.Weekday())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/cPRXZyFnTA